generating a PPT file using a template with placeholders getting the error "getIndex() on null
For your reference my code above, I am trying to generate a PPT file based on a sample template with placeholders, but I am getting an error: "Call to a member function getIndex() on null." How can I fix this? Can anyone help me resolve this issue?
Attached template filetext
I am trying to read the template file on my server and generate the new PPT file, keeping it the same as the template but with placeholder values replaced, and then make it downloadable

Please, edit your question, and post your PHP code. Content on external links can be deleted, and your question would become unanswerable, and of little use to others who might run into the same or similar issue. That being said, I see that your file is supposed to be located at '/home/pim_svc/b.pptx' . Is it here and is it accessible? Are you sure you're not keeping the file open with some program on your machine? Are there any warnings or notices in your error logs?
